# How to stream video, with no errors, when outside the html folder?

Tags: php, html, ubuntu-16.04

On ubuntu 16 This is in the var/www/uploads outside the /html folder, chmod 777 for now (testing).  It will play then have an error if you try to pause the video when it is downloading:

image.php

```
<?php

    $filename = $_GET['filename'];
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    readfile("../uploads/" . $filename);
?>
```

html

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="100%" height="100%"
      controls preload="none" poster='img.png'
      data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source src="image.php?filename=myfile.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Works but within the www/html/uploads, chmod 777. No errors at all.  This is bad practice though:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="100%" height="100%"
      controls preload="none" poster='img.png'
      data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source src="uploads/myfile.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

What else are you suppose to do with mp4 to stop this from happening?

Comment: hint: compare request/response headers and read about http ranges

Comment: Could you guide me to some code examples? :)

Comment: I don't get the negative tick with this being a legitimate question.

Comment: response headers http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php that is helping....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach for this is to use "byte range" headers - this returns only the chunk of the file you need. Wikipedia has a very brief intro (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) but you can google for more.

This is a function I wrote for my projects - you may need to tweak to get it to suit your exact needs, but it's pretty generic and might work out of the box.

```
function serve_file_resumable ($file, $contenttype = 'application/octet-stream') {

    // Avoid sending unexpected errors to the client - we should be serving a file,
    // we don't want to corrupt the data we send
    @error_reporting(0);

    // Make sure the files exists, otherwise we are wasting our time
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }

    // Get the 'Range' header if one was sent
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']; // IIS/Some Apache versions
    } else if ($apache = apache_request_headers()) { // Try Apache again
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($apache as $header => $val) {
            $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;
        }
        if (isset($headers['range'])) {
            $range = $headers['range'];
        } else {
            $range = false; // We can't get the header/there isn't one set
        }
    } else {
        $range = false; // We can't get the header/there isn't one set
    }

    // Get the data range requested (if any)
    $filesize = filesize($file);
    if ($range) {
        $partial = true;
        list($param,$range) = explode('=',$range);
        if (strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes') { // Bad request - range unit is not 'bytes'
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            exit;
        }
        $range = explode(',',$range);
        $range = explode('-',$range[0]); // We only deal with the first requested range
        if (count($range) != 2) { // Bad request - 'bytes' parameter is not valid
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range[0] === '') { // First number missing, return last $range[1] bytes
            $end = $filesize - 1;
            $start = $end - intval($range[1]);
        } else if ($range[1] === '') { // Second number missing, return from byte $range[0] to end
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = $filesize - 1;
        } else { // Both numbers present, return specific range
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = intval($range[1]);
            if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) {
                $partial = false; // Invalid range/whole file specified, return whole file
            }
        }
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
    } else {
        $partial = false; // No range requested
        $length = $filesize;
    }



    // Send standard headers
    header("Content-Type: $contenttype");
    header("Content-Length: $length");  // was $filesize
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    // if requested, send extra headers and part of file...
    if ($partial) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize");
        if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'r')) { // Error out if we can't read the file
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit;
        }
        if ($start) {
            fseek($fp,$start);
        }
        while ($length) { // Read in blocks of 8KB so we don't chew up memory on the server
            $read = ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
            $length -= $read;
            print(fread($fp,$read));
        }
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        readfile($file); // ...otherwise just send the whole file
    }

    // Exit here to avoid accidentally sending extra content on the end of the file
    exit;

  }

  serve_file_resumable ("../uploads/" . $filename, 'video/mp4');
```

Comment: That was some great info and really helped me! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, you can use `X-Sendfile` header to serve any file, including files that are not in a publicly accessible directory.

Example:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('X-Sendfile: ../uploads/'.$filename);
```

It is usually not enabled by default, so you need to add this to `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule xsendfile_module path/to/mod_xsendfile.so
```

Adjust the path as needed and add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
XSendFile on
```

Restart Apache and you are good to go.

This feature is not exclusive to Apache.
In fact, the idea came from Lighttpd.

Comment: This is a lightweight approach.  I like it! :)

Comment: Indeed. It takes just a few lines of PHP and the streaming will be as fast as it can be. Very important if you're serving large files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put you videos to public directory which is accessible for web server 
(for example in symfony framework it is directory `web/uploads/`), 
after that you will be able to use video in src parameter for video tag (as you did it in your second example).

If you already have uploading system which is put video to directory `var/www/uploads` - you have to move such video to public directory, probably you have use some worker or something else. 
You have do it because stream video content from php - it is wrong way...

And also you must not use `777` mod for your videos directory, you must use `755`.

Comment: You can do this and it works, but it exposes your upload folder. This is bad practice and should be avoided as much as possible.  You can make it offline and bring it online through a script like above.  Thanks for the Chmod permissions, but there is also another approach with it being 770.

Comment: You can build some sophisticated system which will avoid leak your videos to world, but key point in my answer that your video should be available for html page in moment when browser will processing video tag...

Comment: The main reason that this isn't the best of practices is the possibility of someone injecting for example a php file into a .jpg or something else and finding out what file this is.  There is more to it than that but it helps prevent scripts being loaded on the server and it being compromised.